# Custom pattern matching in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple python program to read a log file and extract specific values
I have the following log line I want to look out for

```
2022-12-02 13:13:10.539 [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.myTopic1.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=20725269
```

I have many topics such as `myTopic2`, `myTopic3` etc

I want to be able to detect all such lines which show the total incoming bytes for various topics and extract the value.
Is there any easy and efficient way to do so ?
basically I want to be able to detect the following pattern

```
2022-12-02 13:13:10.539 [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.${}.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=${}
```

Ignoring the timestamp ofcourse

Comment: If it were me, I'd look for lines where `'[INFO ] metrics' in line`, then split on `' - '` (space dash space), then split the second have on `", "`, and split those parts on `=` to get name/value pairs.  Now you can store them in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
resultLines = []
resultSums = {}
with open('recent.logs') as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f):
        pieces = line.rsplit('.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=', 1)
        if len(pieces) != 2: continue

        value = pieces[1]

        pieces = pieces[0].rsplit(' [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.', 1)
        if len(pieces) != 2: continue

        topic = pieces[1]
        value = int(value)

        resultLines.append({
            'idx': idx,
            'line': line,
            'topic': topic,
            'value': value,
        })

        if topic not in resultSums:
            resultSums[topic] = 0
        resultSums[topic] = resultSums[topic] + value

for topic, value in resultSums.iteritems():
    print(topic, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I would do it.  This could also be done with a regular expression.

```
data = """\
2022-12-02 13:13:10.539 [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.myTopic1.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=20725269
2022-12-02 13:13:10.539 [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.myTopic1.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=20725269
2022-12-02 13:13:10.539 [metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.myTopic1.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=20725269
"""

counts = {}

for line in data.splitlines():
    if '[INFO ] metrics' in line:
        parts = line.split(' - ')
        parts = parts[1].split(', ')
        dct = {}
        for part in parts:
            key,val = part.split('=')
            dct[key] = val
        if dct['name'] not in counts:
            counts[dct['name']] = int(dct['value'])
        else:
            counts[dct['name']] += int(dct['value'])

print(counts)
```

Output:

```
{'Topic.myTopic1.TotalIncomingBytes.Count': 62175807}
```

Here's a regex version:

```
pattern = re.compile(r".* - type=([^,]*), name=([^,]*), value=([^,]*)")
counts = {}

for line in data.splitlines():
    if '[INFO ] metrics' in line:
        parts = pattern.match(line)
        if parts[2] not in counts:
            counts[parts[2]] = int(parts[3])
        else:
            counts[parts[2]] += int(parts[3])

print(counts)
```

Comment: ```[metrics-writer-1] [INFO ] metrics - type=GAUGE, name=Topic.${}.TotalIncomingBytes.Count, value=${}```

I want to detect the above pattern
so type=GAUGE and TotalIncomingBytes will stay constant

Comment: I assume you can figure out how to modify my code to do that.